# Does anyone know how to convert curl commands to node.js for firebase cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, onesignal

I'm stacking on converting curl commands to Node.js for firebase cloud functions. What I referred to  "https://curl.trillworks.com/" seems to be not working well. The code is below.

Does anyone know how below code should be written by Node.js?

```
 curl --include \
     --request POST \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data-binary "{\"app_id\" : \"YOUR_APP_ID\",
\"identifier\":\"DEVICE_VOIP_TOKEN\",
\"language\":\"en\",
\"timezone\":-28800,
\"game_version\":\"1.0\",
\"device_os\":\"7.0.4\",
\"device_type\":0,
\"device_model\":\"iPhone 8,2\",
\"tags\":{\"a\":\"1\",\"foo\":\"bar\"}}" \
     https://onesignal.com/api/v1/players
```

I'm really thankfully for your help and support.

Comment: I think the humorous answer is "Nobody knows that!"  It's just too tricky  :/

Comment: haha. Yes you must be right!! Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: Unfortunately this is the sort of reason many teams eventually move away from Firebase.  It's amazing but ........ whether or not such cloud services are actually viable for real projects, is a question not yet answered.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will consider about it !!

Answer (score 13):

the short answer with node request npm package is:

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://onesignal.com/api/v1/players',
    headers: { 
       'cache-control': 'no-cache',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
   },
   body: { 
     app_id: 'YOUR_APP_ID',
     identifier: 'DEVICE_VOIP_TOKEN',
     language: 'en',
     timezone: -28800,
     game_version: '1.0',
     device_os: '7.0.4',
     device_type: 0,
     device_model: 'iPhone 8,2',
     tags: { a: '1', foo: 'bar' } },
     json: true 
  };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
 if (error) throw new Error(error);

 console.log(body);
});
```

Here is some life hack, just give me few minutes and I'll tell you how to translate any `curl`

**[UPDATE]** Life hack:

So, there is one app, called [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). Made by Google. The main goal is to make http requests.
There is a lot of use cases what you can do with Postman but I'll tell about 'translating'.
In Postman header you can find tab "Import"

[image: Postman import]

If you click there, you'll see Import tab. Now you're looking for "Paste Raw Text".

[image: Paste Raw Text]

Now you should write any `curl` string to input and press Import.

[image]

Then, it will automatically "translate" your curl to request.
Now you're looking for 'code' tab.

[image]

You click there and see `cUrl` example.
Now you have to click on dropdown list

[image]

And then select your preferred way to make request

[image]

**So**, now you can translate any `curl` request to whatever you like.
And, by the way, you can test your post/put/etc. requests with this app.

Comment: Wow!! Appreciate that!! I`ll be waiting for additional your answer!!

Comment: @RyomaKishimoto updated response. If you find my answer correct/useful, don't hesitate to upvote and select as correct :)

Comment: @Grynets seems not to be working so far still under investigation. 
Thanks for your time a lot though!!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! It worked like a charm